# Theory of Mosfet P channel

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, mosfet-driver

someone can help me explain why is ~6V at source terminal?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After turn on supply on source is 10V, but beetwen source and gate is -10V (gate is invers polarity for source). Transistor go into conduction state but with increase current the voltage on source terminal decrease. Potencial beetwen source and gate decrease and transistor will stop conduction (or better word, current flow decrease). Finaly transistor reach ballance and on source temrinal you get ~6V. 
Because gate is always zero polarization of source have matter.

Answer (score 2):

On that PMOS you shorted Drain and Gate making a "MOS diode".
A MOS diode will drop a voltage of about

\$V_{ds}= V_t + \sqrt(2I_d/K)\$

For the 2N6845 \$V_t\$ is between -2 V and -4 V, let's say \$V_t\$ is 3 V.

The second term depends on the current which can go quite high in your case due to the low series resistor of 1 ohm and the supply voltage of 10 V

The second term will then also be around 3 V resulting from the 4 A which is flowing.

If you make the 1 ohm resistor much higher in value (like 100 kohm) to make \$I_d\$ very small then you will get roughly: \$V_{ds}= V_t\$